# how to expand $\exp(-b x)$ ($b>0$) when $1<x<B$?

Tags: power-series

Let $b>0$, how to expand $\exp(-bx)$ when $1<x<B$?

I am seeking a series expansion like the following ($n_0> 0$):
$$\exp(-bx)=\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{x^n} $$

EDIT:

@GerryMyerson: Thanks for question.

I now think that Taylor series will be sufficient as long as I keep enough terms.

$$\exp(-bx)\approx\sum_{n=0}^{N+1}(-b)^n\frac{x^n}{n!} $$

where $N$ is determined by
$$\frac{B^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}\approx \frac{B^{N}}{(N/e)^N}\frac{B}{\sqrt{2\pi N}}<<1$$

Thus we may require
$$N/e>>B,\qquad 2\pi N>>B^2$$
or
$$N>>\max\left(e B, \frac{B^2}{2\pi}\right)$$

Comment: You want a Laurent series for the exponential function? Do you have  reason to think there is such a thing?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks a lot for your question!

Comment: Not good form to write an equals sign between two things that are manifestly unequal. Also, how does the formula for $\exp(-bx)$ not have a $b$ in it?